# alignment of screen in center when using table layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to display my user screen in center when it is running.i am using table layout.the problem is the screen is always display my user screen on the left side.i hav changed the gravity property of layout as center.but it doesnt make any change.i want to know how can i display my user screen in the center of the screen(emulator).

Comment: please put your xml code so, we can identify what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

To align your table in middle  of the page, you can use

**layout gravity** as **centre** for your **table layout** along with

**layout width and height** set to **wrap content** table as follows

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer

Answer (score 2):

Change TableRow gravity to CENTER_HORIZONTAL

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting what user screen is in your case so post some code too ??As i have understood by your question There is no effect of gravity in table layout u can check for LayoutGravity and Gravity property.

if nothing changes so you just put two empty (means without text) TextViews in the same table row and give some specific width to it like this

Try this